# Unable to get backtrace for error

Tags: debugging, emacs24.4, smartparens, prelude, paredit

I have installed paredit & need to turnoff smartparens. I checked [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/how-do-i-turn-off-smartparens-when-using-prelude) and  I have added

```
(advice-add #'smartparens-mode :before-until (lambda (&rest args) t))
```

to my prelude starter kit. Now when I restart emacs I get this error

```
Symbol's function definition is void: advice-add

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

When i run emacs with

```
emacs --debug-init
```

I dont get any errors or backtrace. It starts normally & everything is working fine.

But when i start emacs directly same error occurs. Can someone tell me how to debug this?

Update: [my emacs config](http://github.com/chillaranand/.emacs.d/).

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you on? (If you're not sure, check by doing `M-x` `emacs-version`.) `advice-add` is part of the [new advice system introduced in Emacs 24.4](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3079/504), so if you're on Emacs 24.3 or older, you can't use it.

Comment: Just checked that. I am using `24.4.1`

Comment: How about (before using `advice-add`)?: `(require 'advice)`

Comment: @lawlist that's also not working :(

Comment: Do you have the library `advice.el` and inside it do you have the function `advice-add`?  `M-x find-library RET advice RET`

Comment: i dont have that. downloaded & added it to my .emacs.d, its working now :D

Comment: Where did you get your emacs? You should not have to download advice.el, it is part of emacs.

Comment: @JordonBiondo from this `ppa:cassou/emacs`. I have installed emacs on 2 systems using same ppa. Just found that one of it has advice.el. Other doesn't have it. May be i have messed it somewhere?

Comment: @ChillarAnand This PPA does not provide Emacs 24.4.  Are you _sure_ that you really have 24.4?  Alternatively, use `defadvice` instead.