# Rebinding smartparens keys using Evil

Tags: key-bindings, evil, smartparens

I use vanilla Emacs with `evil`. I did not install `smartparens` but it is present and enabled on my system as a dependency of something.

I need to rebind the `M-s` keys to something other than the default `sp-splice-sexp`.

The output of `describe-key` for `M-s` is currently:

```
M-s runs the command sp-splice-sexp, which is an interactive compiled
Lisp function in ‘smartparens.el’.

It is bound to M-s, <normal-state> M-s.
```

Going into `smartparens.el`, I am able to see that a `smartparens-mode-map` is defined and `M-s` belongs to it.

I have tried in vain to do:

```
(define-key smartparens-mode-map (kbd "M-s") nil)
```

or

```
(evil-define-key 'normal smartparens-mode-map (kbd "M-s") nil)
```

or

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "M-s") nil)
```

The list of the MELPA packages I use is:

```
auto-package-update atom-one-dark-theme slime
company evil column-enforce-mode paredit evil-cleverparens
highlight-parentheses key-chord
```

One of these packages must be loading `smartparens` and defining the keymap but I can't find which one.
Is there a way perhaps to see which keymap or evil keymap to change?

Comment: Have you tried to disable `smartparens-mode`?

Comment: I have tried `(smartparens-mode -1)` in my `init.el` and also `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (lambda () (smartparens-mode -1)) t)`. No changes whatsoever, the shortcut still exists in `prog-mode` or wherever else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smartparens doesn't add any key bindings by default as `sp-base-key-bindings` is set to `nil`.

Evil-cleverparens has Smartparens as dependency. And evil-cleverparens adds some [additional keybindings](https://github.com/luxbock/evil-cleverparens/blob/8c45879d49bfa6d4e414b6c1df700a4a51cbb869/evil-cleverparens.el#L2006-L2036) by default. This includes setting <kbd>M-s</kbd> to `sp-splice-sexp`.

So you have to unbind <kbd>M-s</kbd> in `evil-cleverparens-mode-map`:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'evil-cleverparens
  (evil-define-key 'normal evil-cleverparens-mode-map (kbd "M-s") nil))
```

Or change `evil-cleverparens-use-additional-bindings` to not use those bindings before loading `evil-cleverparens`:

```lisp
(setq evil-cleverparens-use-additional-bindings nil)
```

Comment: I see. Disabling the additional bindings works for me. But changing the `evil-cleverparens-mode-map` does not. My configuration might be too messy. Anyhow, I consider my problem solved! Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasHoullier changed from `define-key` to `evil-define-key`, should work now.

Comment: Indeed, it works now. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [How do I turn-off smartparens when using prelude?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/how-do-i-turn-off-smartparens-when-using-prelude/54650#54650), the following might do it:

```
(defun rebind-keys ()
  (define-key smartparens-mode-map (kbd "M-s") nil)
)

(add-hook 'smartparens-enabled-hook 'rebind-keys t)
```

Comment: Alright, just tried this to no avail. Nothing seems changed. I tried adding to the hook `'smartparens-enabled-hook` either a key rebinding function or `(smartparens-mode -1)`. Nothing seems to change anything, very puzzling.